# Get primary key(s) from fn_dblog update transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, transaction-log

I need to get the primary key(s) of an updated row from `SQL Server` transaction logs obtained via `fn_dblog`. As I can see, when the `Operation` is either `LOP_MODIFY_ROW` or `LOP_MODIFY_COLUMNS`, the `[RowLog Contents 2]` has the primary key. But it also has some additional data.

I have tried seeing different table structures, and I can see that some octets actually represent the primary key.

Can anyone explain the binary format of data in `[RowLog Contents 2]` for update transactions?